Firebase tools npm install not functioning
I am creating a flutter app and trying to connect it to firebase. I was previously having issues with the node and npm versions, but I have now updated the to the latest version.
When I enter the command
npm install -g firebase-tools

I expected to go through with the installation but instead I get returned with this error message
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\joaqu\.cache\firebase\tools\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\protobufjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Users\joaqu\.cache\firebase\runtime/shell.bat -c -- node scripts/postinstall
npm ERR! '--' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.


I ended up fixing this error by running the npm install -g firebase-tools from the Windows Powershell.
